# Disable password policy in Sql Server Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, windows-container

I am trying to run a development db inside the container instead of my local instance. However, in our local dev db versions we use weak passwords (when db is getting deployed to prod the passwords are strong) so when I try to create a server users inside my container it is complaining about the weak password and deployment of SQL Server Project fails.

Is there a way to turn off strong passwords in SQL Server Container?

Answer (score 16):

When creating the Login use `CHECK_POLICY = OFF`, and then a weak password will be allowed. For example:

```
CREATE LOGIN SampleLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF;
```

But, even if it *is* your Development environment, I still feel you should be creating "good" passwords. Being in Dev/UAT/etc is not an excuse for poor security.

*As per comment, if you are using SQL Server 2017+ use `CHECK_EXPIRATION`*

Comment: We use sql server projects in visual studio. I do not really want to change the user creation code. Is there a way to do it server wide?

Comment: @AlexanderM ALTER the LOGIN

Comment: Not as far as I know @AlexanderM. It's there for good reason. If you want to avoid it, you need to explicitly do so. You either need to include `CHECK_POLICY`or use "secure" passwords (ones that conform with the policy).

Comment: @Larnu, being new member in the company I am not feeling comfortable of doing the change to the "good" passwords at this time. Slowly and surely I am going to try to direct a thoughts of the team on that subject but not today :)

Comment: Then looks like you're need to change the creation scripts to use `CHECK_POLICY = OFF` @AlexanderM . Those are your 2 options I'm afraid. :)

Comment: @AlexanderM How about `ALTER LOGIN LogIn WITH PASSWORD=N'password' , CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION  = OFF`

Comment: That would require the login being created @Sami (which it won't be, as the password is insecure).

Comment: CHECK_EXPIRY doesn't exist as of v2017.